# PHP array of objects - trying to extract key

Tags: php, arrays, woocommerce

I am getting a WooCommerce order product meta_data like this...

```
$item_meta_data = $item_values->get_meta_data();
```

This gives me the following...

```
WC_Meta_Data Object
(
    [current_data:protected] => Array
        (
            [id] => 8795
            [key] => Option 1
            [value] => Yes
        )

    [data:protected] => Array
        (
            [id] => 8795
            [key] => Option 1
            [value] => Yes
        )

)
```

I am confused about the data that is returned, I want to check if Option 1 is set, I have tried to get the key like this...

```
foreach($item_meta_data as $meta_data_item) {
    echo $meta_data_item['key'];
}
```

But this is not working as it is not an array, anyone any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps consider using the [methods provided by this object](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Order_Item.html)

Comment: Have you tried maybe casting it as an array/object first using the `(array)$item_meta_data`or `(object)$item_meta_data`?

Comment: I had looked at the available methods but hadn't been able to make it do what I wanted. Perhaps it is my lack of understanding of the documenation.  Will have a further read

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a magic method in `WC_Meta_Data` class named `__get` .

So you can access protected properties. For example:

```
$item_meta_data->key
```

Comment: That gives me an error... Call to a member function get_data() on array

Comment: @fightstarr20 Same thing happend to me. It's because you have an array with one element in it. So in that case `$item_meta_data[0]->key` would work, - but you should probably refactor your code a bit (sinces `$item_meta_data` is an array of item_meta_data's).

Answer (score 0):

You can access all the data with `$item_meta_data->get_data()` or one specific item with `$item_meta_data->id` or `$item_meta_data->key` or `$item_meta_data->value`.