# Get all order item meta data in an unprotected array in WooCommerce 3

Tags: php, wordpress, object, woocommerce, protected

Is there another method to return meta values for custom attributes that doesn't return a protected array

```
foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_key => $item_values) {
    $item_id = $item_values->get_id();

    $item_meta_data = $item_values->get_meta_data();

    var_dump($item_meta_data); 

}
```

It outputs:

```
object(WC_Meta_Data)#3433 (2) {
    ["current_data":protected]=>
    array(3) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(4690)
      ["key"]=>
      string(14) "pa_second-half"
      ["value"]=>
      string(11) "nutty-butty"
    }
```

I've also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48008628/php-array-of-objects-trying-to-extract-key/48008956#48008956)

```
$item_meta_data = $item_values->get_data();

$item_meta_data['key']
```

Which returns NULL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated**

To get order items meta data in an unprotected array you can use [`WC_Order_Item`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Order_Item.html) method [`get_formatted_meta_data()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Order_Item.html#_get_formatted_meta_data) instead.

> The [`WC_Order_Item`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Order_Item.html) method [`get_formatted_meta_data()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Order_Item.html#_get_formatted_meta_data) has 2 optional arguments:
>
> - `$hideprefix` to hide the prefix meta key *(default is `"_"`)*
> - `$include_all` including all meta data, not only custom meta data *(default is `false`)*

So in the order items foreach loop:

```
foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {
    // Get all meta data in an unprotected array of objects
    $meta_data = $item->get_formatted_meta_data('_', true);

    // Raw output (testing)
    echo '<pre>'; var_dump($meta_data); echo '</pre>';
}
```

You will get an unprotected array of accessible objects with like:

```
  [4690]=>
  object(stdClass)#0000 (4) {
    ["key"]=>
    string(14) "pa_second-half"
    ["value"]=>
    string(11) "nutty-butty"
    ["display_key"]=>
    string(11) "Second half"
    ["display_value"]=>
    string(12) "Nutty butty"
  }
```

> Now you can directly get the value from the **meta key** using the [`WC_Data`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Data.html) method [**`get_meta()`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Data.html#_get_meta) in the order items foreach loop.
>
> **So for `pa_second-half` meta key:**
>
> ```
> foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {
>     $meta_data = $item->get_formatted_meta_data();
>
>     // Get the meta data value
>     $meta_value = $item->get_meta("pa_second-half");
>
>     echo $meta_value; // Display the value
> }
> ```
>
> And it will display: **nutty-butty**

**Related thread:** [Get Order items and WC_Order_Item_Product in Woocommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45706007/get-order-items-and-wc-order-item-product-in-woocommerce-3/45706318#45706318)

Comment: Loic, thank you! You've saved me from a headache or two here!